# Why can't I declare this variable within while loops?

Tags: c, variables

I am VERY new to programming, so forgive me if this question seems a bit stupid, but why is it that when I try to run this code it doesn't work:

```
    int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
    while((25 <= cents) && (cents < 50))
    {
        int quarters = 1;
    }
    while((50 <= cents) && (cents < 100))
    {
        int quarters = 2;
     }
     return quarters;
}
```

But when I try to run this code it works perfectly well?

```
 int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
    int quarters = 0;
    while((25 <= cents) && (cents < 50))
    {
        quarters = 1;
    }
    while((50 <= cents) && (cents < 100))
    {
        quarters = 2;
     }
     return quarters;
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to replace `while` with `if`. If any of the logical operations return true, `calculate_quarters` will run in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a visual picture of your situation:

[image]

For your first code, `quarters` is declared inside a while loop, so it cannot be referenced from an outside scope.

However, for your second code, `quarters` is declared within the method, so it can now be referenced within that scope.